# Platform independent way to find path to libpython (e.g., for use in cmake)

Tags: python, cmake

Is there any platform independent way to get the path to a python installation's libpython, for use as a cmake argument? `sysconfig.get_config_var` gives some pieces but there's no consistent way I can get this working.

On OSX:

- No variable contains the actual basename of the library (libpython2.7.dylib)
- `sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR')` returns the directory libpython2.7.dylib is in (/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib)
- edit: There seems to be a bit of a discrepancy in when sysconfig is reporting a symlink and when it's reporting a real path. `LIBDIR` does in fact contain libpython.2.7.dylib, but what I just noticed is that this is a symlink to /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python.

  `INSTSONAME` points to Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python, the basename of that path, but no variable I can find points to the parent part of that path.

On Ubuntu:

- `sysconfig.get_config_var('INSTSONAME')` gives me the name of the library (libpython2.7.so.1.0).
- No variable contains the directory it's in (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/).

  - `LIBDIR` returns only /usr/lib

Answer (score 1):

CMake python modules: [FindPythonLibs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonLibs.html) and [FindPythonInterp](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonInterp.html).

If those don't work for you just set the next vars when calling cmake `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH`, `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH` and `-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:FILEPAT`, for more info look [here](https://github.com/drufat/cmake/blob/master/FindPython.cmake).

Example:

```
cmake .. -G "Sublime Text 2 - Ninja"
-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=d:\virtualenvs\python362_32
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=d:\virtualenvs\python362_32\libs\python36.lib
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:FILEPAT=d:\virtualenvs\python362_32\include
```

Comment: I started trying to specify these myself because FindPythonLibs didn't seem to be finding the right lib on its own. ~~But actually experimenting some more now, it seems to be doing better if I specify both the path to python and the python include dir but leave the path to the library out~~ Nah, scratch that, seemed to just be a caching thing. It's finding the python installation that comes with OSX, not the version I installed with homebrew.

Comment: @Alec I see... to be honest, I try to avoid (as a golden rule) using system-wide python packages at all! Said otherwise, all my swig modules tend to use specific virtualenvs (include+libs) in the building process. I just need to specify that on the cmake command line. My life is much easier by doing so :) . Out of curiosity, any strong reason why you'd use a system-python distribution at all?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean; I'm not trying to use system-wide python packages, I'm trying to build a wheel for a library to distribute. I tried running cmake from within a virtualenv, but that still didn't let cmake find the right version of libpython.

Comment: Also: I know I can specify the path to the libpython via `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY`. What I'm trying to do is determine, programmatically, what the correct version of libpython to use is (that is: the one that goes with the python installation cmake is using).

Comment: Do you activate the virtualenv before running cmake? If it's so, the virtualenv information will be available in the os.environ. If not, you need somehow to specify which virtualenvs you want to use in the first place. For instance, I've coded a plugin for sublime which allows me to gather all available in a certain project (os.walk) and also the ones coming from some search dirs. Anyway, I'm a little bit confused about which problems you're facing right now, sorry my answer didn't help